# I have a button in each row of a table: How can the OnClick handler tell which row it was called from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**The goal:** ,,

So I've got a Table (Which is initialized as a JQuery DataTable). Each row contains a 'remove me' button, and when that button is pressed, I want to delete the row from the current table.

**What I've tried:**

```
tr = $(this).closest('tr');
$('.my-table-class').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr);
```

**What happens**

No matter what row I click on, the last row is deleted from the table is deleted, *except* if there's only one row in the table, in this situation a javascript error: "TypeError: j is undefined" is thrown from Jquery.dataTable.min.js. Both baffle me.

I can get the *attributes* of the right row - for example, If do something like: `alert($(this).attr("data-name"));` I click on John Smith's row, I'll see 'John Smith' in an alert box... so $(this) is the `a` tag, so why doesn't the .closest() method grab the right `tr`tag?

**My Questions:**

- How do I get 'this' row (the one which contained the button which was pressed) in order to delete it?
- Any idea what's causing the 'TypeError: j is undefined" error when there's only one row in the table?

**Details:**

Here's the rendered (from .jsp) HTML table:

```
<table class="table my-table-class">
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th> </th></tr></thead> 
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td><a href="javascript://" class="my-button-class" data-name="John Smith"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Robert Paulson</td>
            <td><a href="javascript://" class="my-button-class" data-name="Robert Paulson"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Juan Sanchez</td>
            <td><a href="javascript://" class="my-button-class" data-name="Juan Sanchez"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's how I initialize the tables as a Jquery DataTable:

```
$('.st-my-table-class').dataTable( {
            "bInfo": true, 
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]], // sort 1st column 
            "bFilter": true, // allow search bar
            "bPaginate": false,  // no pagination 
            "sDom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">' // (f)ilter bar on top, page (i)nfo omitted
        } );
```

And here's the whole event handler:

```
$('.my-button-class').on("click", function(){ 
tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
$('.my-table-class').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr);
});
```

Comment: Use "parent" instead of closest.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'll give that a try! Any insight into why my approach isn't working?

Comment: .parent() gets you to the TD, parent().parent() gets you to the TR that contains it.

Comment: these are both incorrect suggestions. Closet would work fine in this situation.

Comment: .parent('tr') as well as .parent().parent() both give the exact same behavior as described above... the hell?

Comment: Might it be because you are sending it a jquery object and not the native element node? does fnDeleteRow(tr[0]) do the business?

Comment: @Cory the OP is using the older version of DataTables, your link is to the new version with a different API (where fnDeleteRow is the correct method - http://www.datatables.net/api)

Comment: Just noticed that--sorry. Odd question, but is the table closed? the OP has missing </table>. Probably a typo

Comment: @Paul if you can provide a JSFiddle or similar, which includes the same (old) version of Datatables as you are using, you'll get a straightforward answer instead of all these guesses. (But to add to the guesses, change `tr = ` to `var tr = ` and do as @Dawn suggests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [This JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajq6w0hq/43/) is much closer to what you wanted. Here is the basic code

```
$(function() {
      var dataTable = $('.my-table-class').dataTable();
      $( ".test" ).click(function() {
           var row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
           var nRow = row[0];
           dataTable.dataTable().fnDeleteRow(nRow);
      });     
});
```

which I pulled from this resource [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9312/fndeleterow-with-jquery) that explains in full detail on how it works. In short you need to select the node itself not the jQuery object. You can also use `.first`like so.

```
$( ".test" ).click(function() {
     var row = $(this).closest('tr').first(); 
     dataTable.dataTable().fnDeleteRow(row);
```

Note: I added the "This" text as I don't have the button style/icon.

Comment: Thank you! So .closest('tr') actually returns an object representing the nearest tag, rather than just the string of the tag itself?
Is there not a less obfuscated way to access the actual tag, such as a getter method or something?

Comment: not that I am aware of. However you could create your own function that took in a tag and returned the first node. Then reuse that function where you see fit

Answer (score 2):

As @Dawn suggested, you're passing a jQuery element to `fnDeleteRow`, which is expecting a HTML node.

Simply try:

```
$('.my-button-class').on("click", function () {
    tr = $(this).closest('tr').get(0); // gets the HTML node
    $('.my-table-class').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr);
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/so4s67b0/

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the function it is need to declare a variable and assign our data table to it. Then take the selected row's index into another variable. After that remove the selected row from the data table. .draw(false) will be manage the pagination and no of rows properties in jquery DataTable.

```
    $('.my-button-class').click(function () {

        var tbl = $('.my-table-class').DataTable(); 
        var index = tbl.row(this).index();
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(index);
        tbl.row(index).remove().draw(false);

    });
```

Comment: Ok Trix. First of all in the function it is need to declare a variable and assign our data table to it.  Then take the selected row's index into another variable. After that remove the selected row from the data table.  .draw(false) will be manage the pagination and no of rows properties in jquery DataTable.

Comment: Edit ur answer and add ur explanation there